# Align cells by separator

Tags: excel, vba

I need to align cells by ":"

For example

```
 54,585,889 : 2.0%
  4,585,887 :   
    585,889 : 32.0%
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Find the maximum length of the strings, as well as maximum size of both sides, for example 30, and 20:10 and you can use `Split(Cells(i, j), ":")`, then insert spaces before left side similar to: `Space(Len(Cells(i, j))-MaxLeft) & Split(0) & " : " & Split(1) & (Space(Len(Cells(i, j),MaxRight)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please create the helper column with the following formula

`=REPT(" ",15-FIND(":",A1))&A1`

where `A1` - your original string and 15 - the maximal number of characters before ":" in your data

Then apply the monotype font (e.g. "Courier new") to this column.

Comment: Very concise +1. If the initial string appears as "54,585,889:2.0%" I'd add `=SUBSTITUTE(REPT(" ",15-FIND(":",A1))&A1,":", " : ")`